# Non-adversarial robustness

Tags: estimation, estimators, robust

One measure of an estimator's robustness is the [breakdown point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics#Breakdown_point), which tells us how many adversarial observations are necessary to make the estimator useless.

However, is there a notion of non-adversarial robustness? For example, say we are working in a situation where new observations come from a known distribution. What tools do we have to measure the robustness of current estimators under these new observations?

Answer (score 0):

You can measure aleatoric and epistemic uncertainty of the estimator. Additionally, you can  measure whether a domain shift exists by computing a KL or JS divergence between two distributions.